# Camera Intent doesn't return after picture taken

Tags: android, camera

I've only tested this on two devices(Droid Razr 4.1.2 and Galaxy S3 4.1.1) and it works find on the Razr but on the S3 it attempts to take another picture. How can I fix this.

```
//starts camera
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoPath));
startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO);



//when camera intent is done
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == PHOTO){
                MP = new MediaPackage(photoPath.getAbsolutePath(), MediaPackage.IMAGE);
                if(MP.getThumb()!=null)
                    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.New_Post_Add_Image)).setImageBitmap(MP.getThumb());
            }
        }
    }
```